# How to draw border around circle ImageView in Android?

Tags: android

What I achieved is transform the given Image from square to circle, but I can't get the border now, a simple white border around.

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Drawable drawable = getDrawable();

    if (drawable == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
    Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

    int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();

    Bitmap roundBitmap = getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
    canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0, 0, null);

}

public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
    else
        sbmp = bmp;
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    paint.setDither(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
            sbmp.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f, sbmp.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

}

What is wrong with this code? it worked for others, but here it does not work for me.

[I got this code from here](https://gist.github.com/melanke/7158342)

Comment: add reference from where you have got this code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this works for me:

```
public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
    Bitmap sbmp;
    Log.v("rnd","GETTING CROP:"+mStrokeColor);
    if (bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius) {
        float smallest = Math.min(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
        float factor = smallest / radius;
        sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)(bmp.getWidth() / factor), (int)(bmp.getHeight() / factor), false);
    } else {
        sbmp = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(radius, radius,
            Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xffa19774;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Paint stroke = new Paint();

    final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, radius, radius);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    stroke.setAntiAlias(true);

    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    stroke.setFilterBitmap(true);

    paint.setDither(true);
    stroke.setDither(true);

    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
    stroke.setColor(Color.parseColor("#5f61b6"));
    stroke.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    stroke.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
            radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);

        canvas.drawCircle(radius / 2 + 0.7f,
                radius / 2 + 0.7f, radius / 2 - stroke.getStrokeWidth()/2 +0.1f, stroke);

    return output;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me too. Thanks a lot. Saved me a bunch of time

Comment: While this works, the stroke doesn't look smooth... do you know how I can get it smoother?

Comment: You set an antialias flag on the stroke

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this one saved me a lot of time! :)

Comment: Can anyone answer why 0.7f on the center and 0.1f on the radius?